# How to deploy my Nodejs application on my webpage?

Tags: node.js

Made a very simple Timestamp Microservice app with node that I want to be able to run on a webpage on my website. How would I go about doing this? It currently works fine on my local server.

I feel like this would be very simple but from searching can only find how to deploy to Heroku/AWS.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

//Create an instance of Express for the app and instantiate bodyParser and cors
const app = module.exports = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get(`/dateValues/:dateVal`, (req,res,next) => {
  //gets date from request
  var dateVal = req.params.dateVal;

  //Options for formatting date in natural state
  var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

  if(isNaN(dateVal)) {
    var naturalDate = new Date(dateVal);
    naturalDate= naturalDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    var unixDate = new Date(dateVal).getTime()/1000-21600;

  } else {
    var unixDate = dateVal;
    var naturalDate = new Date((parseInt(dateVal)+21600)*1000);
    naturalDate= naturalDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
  }
  res.json({unix: unixDate, natural: naturalDate});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App is running');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is you want to push this online on your own server, it will be the same as you did in local.

Install your server, install npm/node, push your project on it and run npm start. This will work.

If you want something a bit better for production, you can use a proxy webserver, like apache or nginx and run your nodejs project with pm2

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/ownserver/nginx/oss/trusty/deploy_app.html

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is the easiest deployment platfrom when it comes to node.js application. You can host it for free too. Checkout the url below.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction